# How do you change the default base fork for a github pull request?

Tags: github, repository

Whenever I submit a pull request to a merge a feature branch into the master branch of my own github repository the default value is always the original repository that I forked (see attached screenshot). How do I change the default Base repository to mbigras/phase-0-tracks instead of Devbootcamp/phase-0-tracks? Thanks!
[image]