# Github, dont do default pull request to master

Tags: github, pull-request

Everytime I make a pull-request from my fork to the original repo, Github first opens and compares my branch to the remote master branch. But thats never my target, and because there are so many files different, Github needs some time to complete the compare. Thats very annoying.

How can I mae Github, not to compare to the remote master-branch but to default to another one when I click pull request?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36973589/1375964

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

[image]

Offical reference: https://github.com/blog/2224-change-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request